# What is an "APMAnalyticsMeasurementBackgroundTask"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was testing my app in the simulator when suddenly this error appeared on the console. I have no idea what it even relates to - whether it's Firebase, local notifications, or something else. I can't find any information about it online either. Does anybody know what this error means?

```
[BackgroundTask] Background Task 17 ("APMAnalyticsMeasurementBackgroundTask"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what this is? I just noticed the same in my debugger.

Comment: It is from Firebase. Google's internal AppMeasurement framework uses the APM prefix. Why they don't finish their tasks in time is the real question (as far as I know it is a closed source framework).